# How to sort a 2D list by multiple criterias : integer and alphabet?

Tags: python, list

I have a 2D list (example below), each element consisting of an integer and a string. I want to sort this list so the numbers are descending, but when there are consecutive identical numbers, I instead need it to be sorted alphabetically.

```
myList = [[2, "hello"],[3, "world"]]
```

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

To get a multi-criteria sort, you may give a `tuple` to the `key` parameter. Here you may:

1. look at the number, use a minus `-` for reverse order
2. look at string (if number are equals)

```
myList.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))

# equivalent
myList = sorted(myList, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
```

Application

```
myList = [[2, "hello"], [3, "world"], [2, "hallo"]]
myList.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
print(myList)  # [[3, 'world'], [2, 'hallo'], [2, 'hello']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to do:

```
sorted(myList)
```

Comment: Sorting only sorts by integer not the string

Comment: No, it does... If the two integers are equals, then it sorts by string.